# Jquery cross domain request? I just need a single digit returned, but I can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, web-applications, proxy, cross-domain, dashcode

I am making a dashcode webapp and all I want is a single digit, a 1 or 0 returned from an external server so if there is an easier way to do this please let me know.  I am using the plug in found at http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ to try to make a cross domain request, but everything I am trying isn't working.

When I run this code

```
$.ajax({
  url: "status.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    alert("working" + data);
  }
});
```

everything works perfectly and an alert with the text "working1" is displayed, but when I run this code

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://externalsite.com/status.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    alert("working" + data);
  }
});
```

nothing happens.  Can anyone help?  This is just what I am trying now, I've also tried a .get request and the returned data was "objectObject"  I also tried a php proxy without any luck.  I'm just asking for a simple solution to return a SINGLE number from an external server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can control other server output, put header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

in http response, and load with ajax without plugins or using YQL

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

Comment: This is not supported in all browsers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests (but frankly JSONP may not be, either)

Comment: @Jacek_FH I read that this is supported by safari, to enable it do I just put Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the header of my status.html file?

Comment: in HTTP header, not HTML - for example with PHP its: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: This definitely is the answer I'm looking for, I just can't find a web host who allows me to add this.

Comment: any with php -> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin is making a JSONP request via YQL ([see line 18 here](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js)).

If you load up Firebug or the developer tools in Chrome, do you see the JSONP request being made?